# How does one debug and vectorize the partial derivatives of a radial basis function network when using the softmax loss?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, gradient-descent, softmax

I am trying to run (stochastic or batch) gradient descent when one uses the standard cross entropy (softmax loss):

[image]

when using as a model the [Radial Basis Function (RBF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_network) network (you can watch a lecture form caltech [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O8CfrnOPtLc) if you want) when extended to multiclass classification (easily extended by simply feeding the output of the RBF network to a softmax layer. Note that `P(y=l|x)` is simply computed by passing the output of the RBF network through a softmax layer for each label `l` as follows:

[image]

where `\theta_l` indexes the parameters responsible for doing predictions for label `l`.

In this regard I wanted to optimize my model by computing the derivatives with respect to the parameters. Recall that the parameters to optimize in a radial basis function network are the weights `c` at the final layer and the centers `t` at the first layer. I have implemented and debugged how to compute the derivative with respect to the weights `c`. The code works as expected because the partial derivatives match the numerical derivatives. You can find the unit test code is [here](https://github.com/brando90/research/blob/master/task4_HBF_parts/v4/one_1_layer_HBF/dJ_dc_unit_test.m).

I have also tried writing the code that implements the derivative with respect to the centers but I just can't seem to make my implementation of the derivative match the numerical derivatives. The equation of the derivative of the loss `J` with respect to the centers `t_k` that I am trying implementing is as follow:

[image]

where `h_{\theta_l}` corresponds to the output of the RBF that is in charge of predicting label `l`. In fact, `h_{\theta_l}` is very simple to express:

[image]

My main issue is with computing the derivative of `J` with respect to `t_k` (the equation above). For that, I have implemented the [following function](https://github.com/brando90/research/blob/master/task4_HBF_parts/v4/one_1_layer_HBF/compute_dJ_dt.m) that naively computes it without vectorizing it:

```
function [ dJ_dt ] = compute_dJ_dt(z,x,y,t,c)
%Computes dJ_dc
%   Input:
%       z = (K x 1)
%       x = data point (D, 1)
%       y = labels (1 x 1)
%       t = centers (D x K)
%       c = weights (K x L)
%   Output:
%       dJ_dc = (D x K)
[D,K] = size(t);
[~, L] = size(c);
dJ_dt = zeros(D, K);
for k=1:K
    dJ_dt_k = zeros(D, 1);
    for l=1:L
        c_l = c(:,l);
        dh_dt_l = compute_dh_dt(z,x,t,c_l); %(D x K)
        delta = (y==l);
        dJ_dt_k = dJ_dt_k + dh_dt_l(:,k) * delta;
    end
    dJ_dt(:,k) = -dJ_dt_k;
end
end
```

and it does not match [the numerical derivatives code](https://github.com/brando90/research/blob/master/task4_HBF_parts/v4/one_1_layer_HBF/compute_dJ_dt_numerical_derivatives.m).

I have tried different things to check if it works and I will explain them all here. If anyone has additional ideas, feel free to share them, I sort of feel I ran out of good new ideas to try to debug this.

1. First a good natural question is, is my mathematical derivation of the derivative I am trying to implement correct? Even though I have not explicitly checked the mathematical derivation with someone, I have high confidence that its correct because the derivation for the partial derivative with respect to `c` and `t` in the model are identical and you only change the symbol `\theta` to whatever parameter you have in question. Since I have already implemented the derivative with respect to `c` and it passes all my derivative tests, I would assume the derivation of the derivative with respect to `t` or any parameter `\theta` should be correct. One can see my derivation of this equation at in [math.stack exchange here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1488287/what-is-the-derivative-of-the-cross-entropy-loss-when-extending-an-arbitrary-pre).
2. One option could be that `compute_dJ_dt` doesn't actually implement the equation that I am expecting. This could indeed be the case and to check that I independently implemented a slightly more [vectorized version of that code](https://github.com/brando90/research/blob/master/task4_HBF_parts/v4/one_1_layer_HBF/compute_dJ_dt_vec.m) to see if I was actually implementing the equation that I had down on paper. Since the two version of the equation output the same derivative values, I have high confidence that they are computing, indeed the equation that I suspect (also if anyone has a way of further vectorizing this equation, that would be awesome! The vectorization I added is so trivial that it doesn't seem that interesting or that much of a performance gain, though, it does remove one for loop).

Since the equation I have on paper is (with high probability) correct and the implementation of the equation seems to be correct since two version of it output the same value, then it leads me to conclude that maybe, the numerical derivative code has a bug.

3. The [numerical derivative code](https://github.com/brando90/research/blob/master/task4_HBF_parts/v4/one_1_layer_HBF/compute_dJ_dt_numerical_derivatives.m) is so ridiculously simple that its hard to check what on earth could be wrong with it. The only thing that occurred to me that could be wrong is that it could be that my implementation of the [softmax cost J](https://github.com/brando90/research/blob/master/task4_HBF_parts/v4/one_1_layer_HBF/J.m) is wrong, but I highly doubt it since...I already wrote a unit test for it! Plus, I use it to check the numerical derivatives with respect to `c` and the ones for `c` ALWAYS pass, so I can't imagine `J` to be wrong.
4. The last non-trivial thing to check is that `compute_dh_dt` is being computed correctly. I have written [units tests for dh_dt](https://github.com/brando90/research/blob/master/task4_HBF_parts/v4/one_1_layer_HBF/dh_dt_unit_test.m) and since they match their corresponding numerical derivatives on every run, I would suspect that code is correct.

At this point I am not 100% sure what else to try to I am hoping maybe someone has a good idea or maybe points out the stupid thing I am doing? I am not sure what to think right now. Thanks for the help and time community!

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of a anti-climactic resolution, but I guess it was to be expected because this code seemed to be built from working components so it was bound to be a silly small mistake. The mistake was the in the code above that I pasted I should have been using the `delta` as the difference between indication of label and probability of that label but I forgot to subtract the probability. So the code above is:

```
    delta = (y==l);
```

when it should have been:

```
    prob_y_x_h_x = prob_y_x(h_x); % (L x 1)
    ind_y_l = (y==l);
    delta = ind_y_l - prob_y_x_h_x(l);
```

So the fixed code now passes the numerical tests and it looks as follow:

```
function [ dJ_dt ] = compute_dJ_dt(h_x,z,x,y,t,c)
%Computes dJ_dc
%   Input:
%       z = (K x 1)
%       x = data point (D, 1)
%       y = labels (1 x 1)
%       t = centers (D x K)
%       c = weights (K x L)
%   Output:
%       dJ_dc = (D x K)
[D,K] = size(t);
[~, L] = size(c);
dJ_dt = zeros(D, K);
for k=1:K
    dJ_dt_k = zeros(D, 1);
    for l=1:L
        c_l = c(:,l);
        dh_dt_l = compute_dh_dt(z,x,t,c_l); %(D x K)
        prob_y_x_h_x = prob_y_x(h_x); % (L x 1)
        ind_y_l = (y==l);
        delta = ind_y_l - prob_y_x_h_x(l);
        dJ_dt_k = dJ_dt_k + dh_dt_l(:,k) * delta;
    end
    dJ_dt(:,k) = -dJ_dt_k;
end
end
```

I still don't know how to further vectorize the code above, so I am still happy to receive feedback on that part of the question! Here is the vectorization I have so far:

```
function [ dJ_dt ] = compute_dJ_dt_vec(h_x,z,x,y,t,c)
%Computes dJ_dc
%   Input:
%       z = (K x 1)
%       x = data point (D, 1)
%       y = labels (1 x 1)
%       t = centers (D x K)
%       c = weights (K x L)
%   Output:
%       dJ_dc = (D x K)
[D,K] = size(t);
[~, L] = size(c);
dJ_dt = zeros(D, K);
for l=1:L
    c_l = c(:,l);
    dh_dt = compute_dh_dt(z,x,t,c_l); %(D x K)
    ind_y_l = (y==l);
    prob_y_x_h_x = prob_y_x(h_x); % (L x 1)
    dJ_dh = repmat( ind_y_l - prob_y_x_h_x(l) , D, K); %(D x K)
    dJ_dt = dJ_dt + dJ_dh.*dh_dt;
end
dJ_dt = -dJ_dt;
end
```